# Как реализовать MODBUS slave TCP/IP на NODEMCU ESP8266 на языке LUA?

Tags: lua, esp8266

у меня есть плата NODEMCU ESP8266 LUA со встроенным интерпритатором языка LUA. Пытаюсь сделать на нам устройство к которому будет обращаться OPC сервер через MODBUS TCP/IP и опрашивать его. Но пока не встречал примеров реализации этого протокола на языке LUA именно для ESP8266 поэтому не могу понять как и с чего начать. Было бы удобно написать программу на языке LUA, закинуть программу в контроллер и все. Но долгие поиски в интернете меня все время приводят к ARDUINO IDE, там якобы все реализовано уже:

http://en.trialcommand.com/blog/esp8266-slave-modbus-tcpip-no-libraries/
http://pdacontrolen.com/update-esp8266-industrial-modbus-tcp-ip/

http://pdacontroles.com/actualizacion-esp8266-industrial-modbus/

http://domoticx.com/esp8266-wifi-modbus-tcp-ip-slave/

https://github.com/andresarmento/modbus-esp8266

https://github.com/MaxKravt/WiFi-Modbus-TCPtoRTU

https://github.com/JhonControl/ESP8266_Industrial_ModbusTCP_V2

Но мне бы хотелось не перепрошивать через ARDUINO IDE а написать программу именно на LUA, потому что это очень удобно. Пока не могу понять как это сделать и где найти пример.
Спасибо.

Comment: Какая экзотика... :-)

Comment: Уже почти решил, оказалось очень просто, поднимается TCP сервер на порту 502 на NODEMCU. Сейчас у меня TCP сервер принимает все что приходит от мастера на его айпи и 502 порт и может отвечать. Осталось сделать обработку принятой информации и сформировать ответ. Как закончу, то наверное сам отвечу на свой вопрос...

Comment: Хотя это и не ответ на вопрос, но я бы настоятельно рекомендовал для реализации широко распространённых протоколов, таких как Modbus-TCP использовать уже написанные библиотеки, а не изобретать велосипед... Для указанного Вами устройства библиотека имеется, правда она не на Lua. Установите Arduino IDE и введите в менеджере библиотек запрос "Modbus ESP8266" - версия от Andre Sarmento Barbosa, Alexander Emelianov (на момент написания ответа v.4.1.0) - потрясающе функциональна, проста и удобна! Единственное, что может потребоваться обновить прошивку модулю ESP8266 (для работы SerialPort-а на 11520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начну с простого, как принять пакет от MODBUS TCP устройства:

```
arr = {}
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(502, function(conn)
conn:on("receive", function(sck, payload)
payload:gsub(".", function(c)
table.insert(arr, string.byte(c))
end)
print (table.concat(arr, " "))
    end)
end)
```

Вывод в терминал будет таким:

```
0 1 0 0 0 6 1 3 0 0 0 1
.
.
0 30 0 0 0 6 1 3 0 0 0 1
0 31 0 0 0 6 1 3 0 0 0 1
0 32 0 0 0 6 1 3 0 0 0 1
```

В моем случае OPC сервер, который запрашивает информацию у устройства по протоколу TCP, шлет на указанный в нем IP адрес на 502 порт.
Код, который выше принимает его, записывает в массив и потом выводит в терминал. С массивом можно делать все что угодно.

Как передать пакет в MODBUS TCP устройство? Очень просто:

```
arr = {0,1,0,0,0,6,1,3,0,0,0,1}
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(502, function(conn)
conn:on("receive", function(sck, payload)
buff = ""
for i=1, #arr do
line = string.char(arr[i])
buff = buff .. line
end
sck:send(buff)
   end)
end)
```

В данном случае передаётся массив в ответ на запрос от MODBUS TCP устройства. Зная протокол MODBUS можно формировать массив из нужных переменных в зависимости от запроса.

И на последок код, который принятый пакет записывает в массив отсылает его обратно:

```
arr = {}
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(502, function(conn)
conn:on("receive", function(sck, payload)
payload:gsub(".", function(c)
table.insert(arr, string.byte(c))
end)
local buff = ""
for i=1, #arr do 
line = string.char(arr[i])
buff = buff .. line
end
sck:send(buff)
buff = ""
    end)
end)
```

Это конечно не правильно, MODBUS TCP устройство будет ругаться на неправильный ответ, но в промежутке между приемом и передачей можно модифицировать массив и дать правильный ответ, я думаю что те, кто знает протокол MODBUS сможет понять как правильно ответить.
Я всего лишь отладил прием и передачу, базовый алгоритм, который работает, дальше уже каждый переделает его под свои нужды.
Есть еще один момент на который обращу ваше внимание. Бывает такое, что MODBUS TCP устройство может послать очень длинный пакет состоящий из нескольких не дожидаясь ответа на них и тогда массив моментально станет очень большим и естественно ответ будет таким-же и неправильным. Я решил это очень просто, я проверяю размер принятого пакета, если он равен нужному количеству байт, то после приема выполняется код, если нет, то все пропускается и устройство ждет следующего запроса:

```
if string.len(payload) == 12 then 
.
.
end
```

Эту проверку я делаю сразу после приема пакета и если пакет равен 12 байтам, то код выполняется, если нет, то пропускается и ждет следующий запрос от MODBUS TCP устройства.
Данный код можно переделать под MODBUS RS485, контрольную сумму можно рассчитывать [модулем из прошивки MODEMCU.](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/ow/#owcrc16)

[Здесь можно скомпилировать прошивку с нужными модулями.](https://nodemcu-build.com/)